# Are integral manifolds of a distribution on an open subset of Euclidean space automatically proper?

Tags: differential-geometry, foliations

Suppose I have a smooth distribution on an open subset $M \subset R^n$; i.e. $k$ smooth functions  $X^1(\cdot),\ldots,X^k(\cdot)$ on $M$ such that, at each $p \in M$, $X^i(p) \in R^n, 1 \leq i \leq k$. Assume further that, at each $p$, $(X^1(p),\ldots,X^k(p))$ span a $k$-dimensional subspace of $R^n$. Finally, let this collection of vector fields be in involution, so that the Frobenius Theorem applies and we obtain a foliation $F$ of $M$ by integral submanifolds of dimension $k$.

My question is: Under these conditions, is each leaf $L \in F$ automatically an embedded, proper submanifold? By proper, I mean that $L$ is the image of a map $f$ from some domain in Euclidean space to $M$ such that $f^{-1}(K)$ is compact for every compact $K \subset L$.

I have tried to research this question but come up with nothing (probably because I don't know where to look). If the answer to this question is no, would things change if $k = n-1$ (i.e. if the integral submanifolds were hypersurfaces) and it were true that, for each $p \in M$, the normal to the plane spanned by $X^1(p),\ldots,X^k(p)$ was positive (meaning that each component was non-negative with at least one positive)?

Any information would be appreciated.

---

Edited to change immersed to embedded and to define proper in terms of compact subsets of the leaf $L$ (which, if $L$ is embedded, I guess would be intersections of compact subsets of $M$ with $L$).

Comment: Consider a foliation of the disk of radius $2$ by curves that spiral outward to the unit circle, the unit circle, and curves that spiral inward to the unit circle.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, that would seem to take care of the bulk of my question, but of course in this case the normal condition mentioned in my third paragraph is violated. Does that normal condition change things?

Comment: @user167131 do you refer to a non-vanishing section of the normal bundle here with the phrase normal to the plane and positive?

Comment: Yes, the normal (I'm interested in co-dimension 1 foliations) is positive, meaning at least one component is strictly greater than zero and none are less than zero, and never vanishes. So in fact the "normal bundle" is just a never vanishing, positive vector field.